# Can't find CPU connection for PSU

Tags: power-supply, computer-building

I'm trying make an old computer work by replacing the PSU. I have done this but I couldn't find a place on the motherboard to plug the PSU into the CPU. I'm using a `Gigabyte 7VM333M-RZ`. When I turned the PC on, the PC turned on but the monitor said `No Video Input`, so I guessed that the problem was the PSU CPU connection not being plugged in. I cannot find a CPU connection to plug the PSU into.

Comment: Do you have a speaker connected?  Does it beep at you at all when you turn it on?  Do the fans or HDD spin when you press the power button?

Comment: No speakers. No beeping. Fans and HDD both spin when I turn it on

Comment: Does the HDD Activity LED just glows continuously?

Comment: What is the PSU model? Are you connecting to monitor via VGA port? Have you tried using other VGA cables? Is the motherboard mounted to the case properly? What was the issue with your old computer when you decided that changing PSU will solve this problem?

Comment: @alljamin I replaced the psu in the newer pc as it showed no signs of life when I tried to turn it on

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the [manual for your motherboard](http://download1.gigabyte.eu/Files/Manual/motherboard_manual_7vm333m-rz_e.pdf) the processor is powered via the PSU connector which is plugged into the socket labelled ATX (see page 6).  It is clear you have integrated graphics on the motherboard.  Just ensure you have a VGA monitor plugged into the VGA connection (again, see page 6).

If this is still not sorting the problem out, turn the computer off and whilst the computer remains off, clear the CMOS by shorting the pins labeled `CLR_CMOS` (again, see page 6).  You only need to short these pins for a short period of time.  Then remove the short and turn your computer back on.  Your problem should then be solved.

If not then there is a problem with the motherboard.

Answer (score -1):

CPU is probably getting power from motherboard otherwise PC wouldn't turn on at all.
Your problem is between graphics card and monitor. Or you are trying to use it without a dedicated graphics card and your CPU doesn't have integrated graphics because it's old.

Comment: The computer doesn't have dedicated graphics so I'm going to change the monitor to see if that will make a difference

Comment: What is your CPU model?

Comment: Sorry, I have absolutely no idea. I plugged into another monitor and the same thing happened. Could it be that the motherboard is damaged it I haven't plugged the psu cables into the correct places?

Comment: How old is this PC? I think your CPU doesn't have integrated graphics. You may have to get a dedicated GPU.

Comment: The PC is probably around 10 years old. I thought that it should work as the only change I've made is change the psu. Everything else has stayed the same. Although, I think I might have pushed the motherboard down slightly at one end when attaching the biggest connection (I think it's 20 pin), would this have had an effect, i.e break the motherboard?

Comment: Motherboard should be okay I think. check your RAM. Do you have a buzzer(http://www.baaqii.com/promanage/productimage/Ewhole/A/A1073-1.jpg)? Are you geting POST(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test)?

Comment: What exactly are you plugging the monitors into? Do you have a video card?